# fail2ban with PermitRootLogin without-password?

Tags: ssh, security, fail2ban

I tried to choose a title that cover the topic:

Why should I use fail2ban (or similar programs) if I've my `PermitRootLogin` set to `without-password`?

A very trusted and experienced sysadmin that I know suggested me to also install fail2ban as out of the box can protect my custom server from bruteforce attacks as they consume resources (and I've a limited amount of resources available).

Another very trusted and experienced sysadmin that I know suggested me to not install fail2ban as I've disabled the password authentication and so there is no point in preventing a bruteforce as there are no passwords that will ever work.

I'm really confused.

Thank you all for any help you may give me.

Comment: Belt and suspenders. Build layers of security.  What happens if your sshd_config gets changed at some point?  What happens if the attacker probing SSH decides to start attacking other services on the host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, personally I'm not a fan of `PermitRootLogin` being set to anything but `no` (what if someone compromises your SSH key, which is presumably on an insecure machine? Better to force people to use SSH keys to log in to a normal user account, then use a password to `sudo` or `su` to root IMHO).

Broadly though, Fail2Ban and `PermitRootLogin without-password` are designed to protect against different threats.

Fail2Ban protects you from brute-force attacks: Someone trying to guess your (normal user) passwords, or someone who has "acquired" a bunch of SSH keys trying all of them to see if any work to get in to your system -- It will lock out attackers after a certain number of attempts, and alert you to the problem so you can take appropriate action.
Fail2Ban can also protect other services besides just SSH (which is important if you have say an FTP server).

`PermitRootLogin without-password` protects you against someone guessing the root password for SSH access (It prevents password-guessing brute-force attacks entirely, since even if they guess right the password still *won't work*).
It doesn't protect any other services on the host, nor does it protect you against someone acquiring a valid SSH key (so you're at the mercy of all the users who have valid keys for your root account, and the security of their laptops/cell phones/etc).